# Nsubstitute Mocking readonly property

Tags: nsubstitute

is there any way I can Mock read-only property

```
       public string DefaultHostName { get; }
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/websites/Azure.ResourceManager.AppService/src/Generated/WebSiteData.cs

Answer (score 0):

You could use Nsubstitute Returns method :

```
var myObjectMock = Substitute.For<MyClass>();
myObjectMock.DefaultHostName.Returns("DefaulHostName");
```